# Windows 7 (64-bit): "C:\Program Files" versus "C:\Program Files (x86)"

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, filesystems, 32-bit, directory-listing

I am running Windows 7 Home Premium (64-bit).

I have read that the difference between `"C:\Program Files"` versus `"C:\Program Files (x86)"` is that one is for `32-bit executables` whereas the other is for `64-bit executables`.

Could someone please point out to me `which is which?` (I ask because I have been following the installation instructions for some software I downloaded and the instructions do not make it clear which is which). Thanks.

---

NOTE: This question is a simplified version of [this one](https://superuser.com/questions/89540/why-does-windows-7-install-64-bit-apps-in-the-program-files-x86-folder-can-i), which contains more detail on the issue.

Comment: Perhaps also see [Why does 64-bit Windows need a separate “Program Files (x86)” folder?](http://superuser.com/questions/442246/why-does-64-bit-windows-need-a-separate-program-files-x86-folder?rq=1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the folder `C:\Program Files (x86)` is for 32-bit application  and `C:\Program Files` is for 64-bit application that can run on windows 64 bit.

If you have a windows 32 bit you have only `C:\Program Files` on your C drive

Answer (score 2):

On any 64-bit version of Windows:

- The “Program Files” folder is for 64-bit programs.
- The “Program Files (x86)” folder is for 32-bit programs.

This is to ensure compatibility with legacy versions of Windows programs.

Windows versions which are 32-bit only have a "Program Files" directory.